# Rails 5, Simple Form with Select2-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, simple-form

I'm trying to figure out how to use select2 with simple form in my rails 5 app.

I am using acts as taggable on in the app.

I have installed this gem in my gem file:

```
gem 'select2-rails'
```

I tried to install this gem in my gemfile, but I get an error saying that it cant be found. I'm wondering if it isnt compatible with Rails 5 (given the last update was 2015).

```
# gem 'select2_simple_form'
```

My objective is to make a form input field that users can complete by selecting 5 predefined tags available on the tagged model.

I've tried the solutions put forward in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762999/select2-rails-act-as-taggable-on-rails-4-issue) and this post and I've tried every example in this documentation stream. I cant get any of them working.

In my application.js, I have:

```
//= require select2
```

I have also tried each of these:

```
// $(document).ready(function() {
//   $(".js-example-basic-multiple-limit").select2({
//   maximumSelectionLength: 2
//   });
//
// });

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.multiple-input').each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [','],
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      placeholder: 'Separated by comma'
      });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-row #proposal_randd_field_list, .input-row #proposal_randd_field_list').select2({tags:[]})
});
```

I cant get this to work at all. When I inspect the google console - I don't get any js errors, but I also don't get a working select 2 functionality. I can just select in the ordinary way that simple form allows from a drop down menu.

My objective is to have the content of my Randd::Field model (which has an attribute called :title; those titles are the tags on the proposal model and stored in a randd_field_list in that proposal model) accessible as a searchable, drop down list as shown [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) (under the heading Loading remote data).

Does anyone know how to achieve this in rails using simple form. The documents don't line up at all.

My current attempt is:

```
<%= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title),  :title, :title, {:selected => @proposal.randd_field_list, :include_blank => true}, input_html: {:class => 'multiple-input', :multiple => true} %>
```

The above does not allow me to select multiple tags (with any variation of the application.js function enabled).

I have also tried:

```
<!-- <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"> -->
<!--<input type="hidden" id="ajax-example" /> -->

<%#= f.label :randd_field %>
<%#= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title),  :title, :title,  input_html: { class: 'multiple-input', multiple: "multiple" } %>

<%#= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title),  :title, :title, {:selected => @proposal.randd_field_list, :include_blank => true} %>
<!-- </select> -->
  <!-- <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"> -->
     <!-- <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
 </select> -->
        <%#= f.text_field :randd_field_list, input_type: "textbox", name:"proposal[randd_field_list][]", html_options: { style: 'width: 100%' } %>
        <%#= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title),  :title, :title, {} %>
        <%#= f.input 'randd_field_list',
       options_from_collection_for_select(@randd_fields, :title, :title),
       multiple: true %>
       <%#= f.collection_select 'randd_field_list',
      options_from_collection_for_select(@randd_fields, :title, :title),
      multiple: true %>
       <%#= f.input :randd_field_list,:collection => @randd_fields,:label_method => :title,:value_method => :title,:label => "Fields" ,:include_blank => false, :multiple => true %>
```

None of these work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your post looking for some Rails 5 update info. I'm a newbie, but I'm grappling with the problem of too many small gems. I'm wondering if you shouldn't give up on `select2` and do what you need using just `simple_form`? Just a thought because I have no idea how to handle tags as you're trying to do.

Good luck.

Comment: I actually gave up on rails. I'm learning react. There are so many things about rails/jquery that seem to be out of date and unsupported. I just haven't been able to learn after 4.5 years of trying. Thanks anyway for the tip, but I gave up on rails and jQuery.

Comment: @Mel. Good luck. My quick read on React is that it's not a complete solution.

Comment: No - I'll use it with the rails backend for now.