# How to use select2-rails with acts_as_taggable_on (simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, acts-as-taggable-on, select2-rails

I need to allow users to select tags for their posts, but from closed list (let's say only admin can add new tags, or they are predefined in other way). Each post can have many tags, so it needs to be multiselector. Unfortunately, after adding select2-rails tags weren't able to be saved in DB. How can I fix it? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762999/select2-rails-act-as-taggable-on-rails-4-issue?lq=1) doesn't work for me.

PostsController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: _('Post created')
    else
      render :new, notice: _('Something went wrong')
    end
  end

  def show
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def edit
    authorize @post
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: _('Post updated')
    else
      render :edit, notice: _('Something went wrong')
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @post
    if @post.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: _('Post deleted')
    else
      redirect_to @post, notice: _('Something went wrong')
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :header, :content, :tag_list)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  acts_as_ordered_taggable_on :tags

  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, :header, :content, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :header
  = f.input :content, input_html: { rows: 10 }
  = f.input :tag_list, collection: @tags, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'tags' }
  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-warning'
= link_to _('Back'), :back
```

application.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tags').select2({
    placeholder: 'Click to select',
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it was much easier than I thought. All I had to do was permit `tag_list` as an array `tag_list: []` (default syntax `:tag_list` won't save tags in DB, as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651759/rails-acts-as-taggable-on-with-select2-and-simple-form) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762999/select2-rails-act-as-taggable-on-rails-4-issue?lq=1)), but only this change caused strange behaviour - saving tags ids instead of names. Second thing, which was not mentioned in above links, is to explicity define label and value method for selector (it is important, because on default it would pass ids of tags, not tags names, so it will create new tags with names identical to ids of previous tags).

In controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :header, :content, tag_list: [])
end
```

And in View:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :header
  = f.input :content, input_html: { rows: 10 }
  = f.input :tag_list, collection: @tags, value_method: :name, label_method: :name, input_html: { multiple: true, class: 'tags' }
  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-warning'
= link_to _('Back'), :back
```

Comment: what is label_method and how is it different than value_method? thanks.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss label_method is what you display in selector, value_method is what you are passing to save to db.
e.g. if you have categories, and posts have category_id in db, you want to show category name in selector and pass category id to db - you set label_method as :name (category name) and value_method as :id (category id).